# unable to display success message after editing the row in jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jqgrid

I'm developing a web based application using bootstrap.
I'm trying to implement inline editing in my grid on page load but i'm facing some issue while displaying the success or failure message after performing edit function.

**Here is my code :**

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var GetUrl = Web_Path + '/Test/TestHandler/GetTestData/' + AjaxHandlerName;

                jQuery("#jqGrid-container").jqGrid({
                    url: GetUrl,
                    datatype: 'json',
                    mtype: 'POST',
                    postData: { SearchInfo: function () { return getSearchPostData() } },
                    colNames: [' ', 'ID', 'Name', 'ContactNo', 'EmpId', 'MailId', 'RoleName'],
                    colModel: [
                    { name: 'myac', index: '', width: 80, fixed: true, sortable: false, resize: false,
                        formatter: 'actions',
                        formatoptions: {
                            keys: true,
                            delOptions: { recreateForm: true, beforeShowForm: beforeDeleteCallback }
                        }
                    },
                                { name: 'Id', index: 'Id', hidden: true, editable: true },
                                { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', validation: { required: true }, sortable: true, editable: true, editoptions: { size: "40", maxlength: "50"} },
                                { name: 'ContactNo', index: 'ContactNo', sortable: false, editable: true, editoptions: { size: "20", maxlength: "30"} },
                                { name: 'EmpId', index: 'EmpId', sortable: false, editable: true, editoptions: { size: "20", maxlength: "30"} },
                                { name: 'MailId', index: 'MailId', sortable: false, editable: true, editoptions: { size: "40", maxlength: "50"} },
 {name: 'RoleName', index: 'RoleName', sortable: false }
  ],


                    editurl: ISM_Web_Path + '/Test/TestHandler/UpdateTestContacts/' + ISMAjaxHandlerName,                 

                    ajaxRowOptions: {
                    afterEditRow: function (rowid, cellname, value, iRow, iCol) {
                    alert('success');
                    }
                    },                 
                    serializeRowData: function (postdata) {
                    return { ContactInfo: JSON.stringify(postdata) };                     
                    },
                    jsonReader: {
                        id: 'Id',
                        repeatitems: false
                    },
                    height: "100%",
                    pager: '#jqGrid-pager',
                    rowNum: 10,
                    rowList: [10, 20, 30],
                    sortname: 'Id',
                    sortorder: 'desc',
                    viewrecords: true,
                    caption: "JQ grid data",
                    loadComplete: function () {
                        var table = this;
                        updatePagerIcons(table);                       
                    }
                });
});

 function getSearchPostData() {
            var searchData = {};
            searchData.Id=1;

            return JSON.stringify(searchData);
        }
 function updatePagerIcons(table) {
            var replacement =
                    {
                        'ui-icon-seek-first': 'icon-double-angle-left bigger-140',
                        'ui-icon-seek-prev': 'icon-angle-left bigger-140',
                        'ui-icon-seek-next': 'icon-angle-right bigger-140',
                        'ui-icon-seek-end': 'icon-double-angle-right bigger-140'
                    };
            $('.ui-pg-table:not(.navtable) > tbody > tr > .ui-pg-button > .ui-icon').each(function () {
                var icon = $(this);
                var $class = $.trim(icon.attr('class').replace('ui-icon', ''));

                if ($class in replacement) icon.attr('class', 'ui-icon ' + replacement[$class]);
            })
}

 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">           
            <table id="jqGrid-container" class="ui-jqgrid ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
            </table>
            <div id="jqGrid-pager">
            </div>           
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Handler function**

```
 public void UpdateTestContacts(HttpContext context)
        {
            TestContact contactInfo =new TestContact();
            string jsonData = context.Request.Params["ContactInfo"];
            MemoryStream TestContactMs = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonData));
            DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(TestContact));
            contactInfo = (RelationshipContact)serializer.ReadObject(TestContactMs );              
            //call manger function
            // return true or false
        }
```

**TestContact.cs**

```
 public class TestContact
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string ContactNo { get; set; }

        public string EmpId { get; set; }

        public int RelId { get; set; }

        public int TypeId { get; set; }

        public string MailId { get; set; }

        public string RoleName { get; set; }       
    }
```

I have used **jquery.jqGrid.min.js**.

I'm unable to display success message after editing the row successfully.
I have used **afterEditRow**
Please help me out.

Answer (score 2):

There are no `afterEditRow` callback function inside of `ajaxRowOptions`. I recommend you to use `aftersavefunc` callback function of inline editing which can be specified as `afterSave` function of `formatoptions`:

```
formatter: 'actions',
formatoptions: {
    keys: true,
    afterSave: function (rowid, response, postdata, options) {
        alert("success");
    },
    delOptions: { recreateForm: true, beforeShowForm: beforeDeleteCallback }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 ajaxRowOptions: {
                  success: function (data, textStatus) {
                    if(textStatus=="true")
                    {
                    alert('success');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    alert('failure');
                    }
                  }
 }
```

I'm returning **true in handler**.
Above code is working for me.